# Angular 2 - CSS background-color not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm having problems defining body's background color, using Angular 2. I've tried change html, body, container-fluid colors, but it does not change. I also changed html and body in my app.component.css, but it did not work.

The rest of my css is ok, so the browser got the stylesheet

app.component.html:

```
<jogo></jogo>
```

app.component.css:

```
html, body{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

jogo.component

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="showPlay">
    <div class="row">      
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8c">
            <p align="center">
                Qual é<br/>a<br/>Música?
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        <div align="center">
            <button type="button" class="rounded-circle">Play</button>
        </div>
  </div>    
</div> 
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="showJogo">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="tocador">
        Segunda
        <audio controls>
            <!-- caminho devera ser trocado pelo do firebase? -->
            <source src="/assets/Queen - Love of My Life.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="pontos">Pontos</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="tempo">Tempo</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="pergunta">Pergunta</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

jogo.component.css:

```
body{
    background-color: pink;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #990000;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: rotate(-12deg);

}
button {
    background-color: #990000;
    color: #F0D1B7;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 10%;
}
```

CSS NOT APPLIED AT BODY TAG:
[image: CSS NOT APPLIED AT BODY TAG]

STYLESHEET LOADED:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Angular creates [Shadow Dom](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) for applying styling to different components.

To apply styling to root elements, we can use style.css in the root folder.

**style.css**

```
html, body{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bootstrap, so the container-fluid fills the whole screen. Try to give the element background-color with !important , you just create a new class for the main container, gives background-color with !important to override the container fluid. I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a style for body so depending on your loading order.

Your style might be getting overridden by the Bootstrap default background-color of #fff (white);

You can load your local CSS after the bootstrap CSS.

Or add !important to your style (usual not a good practice).

Answer (score 0):

Angular scopes component styles to the target components, so any selector targeting elements outside the component will not get applied. For instance,
`.tout {color: yellow}` will get translated to something like `.tout[_ngcontent-kls-c1] {color: yellow}`. In the same way, `body {background-color: pink}` will get translated to something like `body[_ngcontent-kls-c1] {background-color: pink}`
So you need to put your global styles in a global stylesheet like src/styles.css